# Max and min value of a 2-variables function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, partial-derivative

I have to solve the following problem about finding  the min and max value of the following function in its domain :
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi xy^4}{2})}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^4}}$$
I started by looking at the domain, which is $x^2+y^4\le1$. I calculated the two partial derivatives
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(f(x,y)\right) $ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(f(x,y)\right)$
and looked at the following two equations:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(f(x,y)\right)=0 \space\land\space \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(f(x,y)\right)=0$$
The problem is that I cannot find the solution to this non-linear system of two equations. Any tips?